# Plot only 1s of a binomial matrix

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I would like to plot all the 1s of a binomial matrix (code given below). I need to histogram y-axis to be the frequency and the x-axis to be all the matrix columns.

```
#code for matrix    
prevalence <- 0.01
Infected <- sapply(1:10, function(p) rbinom(500, 1, prevalence))
```

I tried using `hist(Infected)` but this just gave me the frequency of 0 and 1, with no column details.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you need, but you can try counting the entries in the matrix. For instance: `plot(colMeans(Infected))`

Answer (score 3):

Use `colSums` to get the number of `1` and then `barplot` to get a bar per column.

```
set.seed(42)
prevalence <- 0.01
Infected <- sapply(1:10, function(p) rbinom(500, 1, prevalence))

barplot(colSums(Infected), names.arg = 1:10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try `replicate` and `sum(rbinom(...))`, e.g.,

```
hist(replicate(10, sum(rbinom(500, 1, prevalence))))
```

or `colSums`

```
hist(colSums(matrix(rbinom(500 * 10, 1, prevalence), 10)))
```

and you will obtain the plot like below

[image]